# Pre train a model (classifier) in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, model, classification, pre-trained-model

I would like to pre-train a model and then train it with another model.

I have model `Decision Tree Classifer` and then I would like to train it further with model `LGBM Classifier`. Is there a possibility to do this in scikit learn?
I have already read this post about it https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28512/train-new-data-to-pre-trained-model.. In the post it says

> As per the official documentation, calling fit() more than once will
> overwrite what was learned by any previous fit()

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1) 

# Train Decision Tree Classifer
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

lgbm = lgb.LGBMClassifier()
lgbm = lgbm.fit(X_train,y_train)

#Predict the response for test dataset
y_pred = lgbm.predict(X_test)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for stacked classifiers.

In this approach, the predictions of earlier models are available as features for later models.

Look into [StackingClassifiers](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.html).

Adapted from the documentation:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier

estimators = [
     ('dtc_model', DecisionTreeClassifier()),
 ]

clf = StackingClassifier(
                estimators=estimators, 
                final_estimator=LGBMClassifier()
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible at present. According to the doc at https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html?highlight=init_model, you can continue training the model if the model is from lightgbm.

I did try this setup with:

```
# dtc
dtc_model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
dtc_model = dtc_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    
# save
dtc_fn = 'dtc.pickle.db'
pickle.dump(dtc_model, open(dtc_fn, 'wb'))
    
# lgbm
lgbm_model = LGBMClassifier()
lgbm_model.fit(X_train_2, y_train_2, init_model=dtc_fn)
```

And I get:

```
LightGBMError: Unknown model format or submodel type in model file dtc.pickle.db
```

Answer (score 1):

As [@Ferdy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70193071/4574633) explained in his post, there is no simple way to perform this operation and it is understandable.

Scikit-learn `DecisionTreeClassifier` takes only numerical features and cannot handle `nan` values whereas `LGBMClassifier` can handle those.

By looking at the decision function of `scikit-learn` you can see that all it can perform is splits based on `feature <= threshold`.

On the contrary `LGBM` can perform the following:

- `feature is na`
- `feature <= threshold`
- `feature in categories`

Splits in decision tree are selected at each step as they best splits the set of items. They try to minimize the node impurity (giny) or entropy.

The risk of further training a `DecisionTreeClassifier` is that you are not sure that splits performed in the original tree are the best, since you have new splits capabilities with `LGBM` that might/should lead in better performance.

I would recommend you to retrain the model with `LGBMClassifier` only as it might be possible that splits will be different from the original `scikit-learn` Tree.